# Rowsize returning to default after refresh

Tags: angularjs, tapestry

I set the row size using t:rowsPerPage to a different value in a grid, but once I refresh the page it returns to the default value. How do I avoid that?

```
<table t:type="grid" id="txnResultGrid" t:id="txnResultGrid" t:source="listTransactions" 
       t:rowsPerPage="20" t:model="txnGridModel" t:options="txnGridOptions" t:mode="false"
       t:row="txnInfo" t:tableInformation="gridInfo" t:exclude="feeExponent,vatExponent">
```

Comment: why every attribute has `t:` prefix?

Comment: Because these all are table attributes. ...

Comment: the t: is actually the Tapestry (framework) namespace prefix and has nothing to do with tables

Comment: How do you change the value? Your .tml has a fixed value of 20... ?

Comment: Yes Nathan i set 20 from tml default, so is there any other way these values should persist when i set to 40 or 80 etc?